# New to OOP - How to store variables in array?

Tags: php

I'm new to OOP (and programming for that matter, started a few months ago) so classes and objects are still a bit of a foreign concept to me. Anyhow, I'm attempting to store a mix of strings and variables in an array for later processing. See method `drawtable()`. `drawtable()` prints the `tableheaders` just fine, but `tableheaders` is just an array of strings. The issue comes when I try to print the `tablelink`, and `text` properties, which I've attempted to include variables in. What am I doing wrong here? Note: the session variables output fine.

I would also appreciate any general critiques of the code below, as I'm new and attempting to nip any bad habits in the bud. Many thanks.

```
<?php
class table{

    function __construct($type){
        if($type == "submittals"){

            $this->tableheaders = array('Specification Section', 'Submittal #', 'Description', 'Vendor or Manufacturer', 'Date Received By GC', 'File', 'Date Submitted', 'File', 'Date Requested for Review', 'Date Returned to GC', 'File', 'Status', 'Date Returned to Subcontractor or Vendor');

            $this->query = "***SELECT Query***";

            $this->tablelink = array("/pd/upload/" . $_SESSION['current_project'] . "/s/" . $row['file'], "edit_submittal.php?submittal_id=", "edit_submittal.php?submittal_id=" . $row['submittal_id']);

            $this->text = array($row['number'] . " - " . $row['name'], $this->row['submittal_num']);            
        }
    }

    function drawtable() {
        $this->numheaders = count($this->tableheaders);

        $this->db = mysqli_connect(***db connection info***);
        $this->results = mysqli_query($this->db, $this->query);
                $this->num_results = mysqli_num_rows($this->results);

        echo "  <table border=\"1\">
                    <tr>";  
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->numheaders; $i++) {
                            echo "<th>" . $this->tableheaders[$i] . "</td>";
                        }
        echo "      </tr>";

        for ($j=0; $j < $this->num_results; $j++) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->results);

            echo "  <tr>";

            for($k = 0; $k < $this->numheaders; $k++) {
                echo "  <td><a href=\"" . $this->tablelink[$k] . "\">" . $this->text[$k] . "xxx</a></td>";
            }

        }
        echo "      </tr>
                </table>";
    }
}
?>
```

---

Update:Okay well this works, but I'm sure it's still has an air of noob sloppiness. Suggestions? Thanks

```
<?php
class Table{

    function __construct($type){
        if($type == "submittals"){

            $this->table_headers = array('Specification Section', 'Submittal #', 'Description', 'Vendor or Manufacturer', 'Date Received By GC', 'File', 'Date Submitted', 'File', 'Date Requested for Review', 'Date Returned to GC', 'File', 'Status', 'Date Returned to Subcontractor or Vendor');

            $this->query = "***SELECT query***";    
        }
    }

    function draw_table($type) {
        $this->num_headers = count($this->table_headers);

        $this->db = mysqli_connect(***db connection***);
        $this->results = mysqli_query($this->db, $this->query);
        $this->num_results = mysqli_num_rows($this->results);

        echo "  <table border=\"1\">
                    <tr>";  
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->num_headers; $i++) {
                            echo "<th>" . $this->table_headers[$i] . "</td>";
                        }
        echo "      </tr>";

        for ($j=0; $j < $this->num_results; $j++) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->results);

            if($type == "submittals") {
                $this->table_link = array("/pd/upload/" . $_SESSION['current_project'] . "/s/" . $row['file'], "edit_submittal.php?submittal_id=", "edit_submittal.php?submittal_id=" . $row['submittal_id']);
                $this->text = array($row['number'] . " - " . $row['name'], $row['submittal_num'], $row['description']);         
            }

            echo "  <tr>";

            for($k = 0; $k < $this->num_headers; $k++) {
                echo "  <td><a href=\"" . $this->table_link[$k] . "\">" . $this->text[$k] . "</a></td>";
            }

        }
        echo "      </tr>
                </table>";
    }

    function get_table_headers() {
        echo $this->table_headers;
    }
    function get_query() {
        echo $this->query;
    }
    function get_table_link() {
        echo $this->table_link;
    }
    function get_text() {
        echo $this->text;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Answer to your title is [here](http://bd1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: As a 'general critique': class names are by convention started with a capital letter to be able to distinguish class names from function and variable names. Functions and variables are both started with a lower case letter, but functions usually have `()` behind them. For all three (function, variable and class names): if a name consists of more than one word (which is perfectly fine) new words in a name are started with a capital (but the first letter only with classes!) to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like this. You can't access `$row` in the constructor as over there the variable is undefined. You expect PHP to realize that it should replace the content of `$row['name']` etc. later when you actually use the string. However, why should it? Instead PHP can't find `$row` at all and everything goes wrong. Actually, you should get an error telling you that `$row` is undefined.

Overall there is quite a lot wrong with your code. Sorry to say so, but you do not yet grasp the general concept of OOP at all. And it would take way too long to explain this here. And apparently there are some thing not even related to OOP, which you don't know. Scopes for example and about when and where variables exist.

Comment: Well that's okay, right now. The entirety of my programming career consists of reading 6 chapters of a PHP book over the last couple months. I expect that there are many things that I don't know. I only started attempting to learn OOP yesterday. 

That said, your comment that I can't access $row in the constructor because it is undefined there makes sense and I recognize that as the problem. What can I do to kind of wait to look for $row until I get to $tablelink and $text? General direction is all I'm looking for here.

Thanks

Comment: You have to construct your string in `drawtable()` within the loop, because only there `$row` is defined. You don't even need to use a class there, because you don't have a state. Employing a class is only useful if your program has some kind of state that has be kept track of. In instance/class variables you can store information about what your program is doing right now. If you don't have those,  just go with a simple function. (This is very much simplified!)